# What exactly mean API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, macos

What exactly mean `API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("xxx", ios(4.2, 9.0))` ?

1. The function is available in 9.0 but marked as deprecated in 9.0 and not exists in 9+ ?
2. Or the function is available in 9.0 but marked as deprecated in 9.0 and still exists in 9+ ?
3. Or that The function is not available at all in 9.0

Exactly I m concern about this 2 functions :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options API_AVAILABLE(ios(9.0)); // no equiv. notification. return NO if the application can't open for some reason
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("application:openURL:options:", ios(4.2, 9.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
```

Does I understand well that from ios 9.0 included `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` will not be called anymore and only `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options` will be call ?

Comment: Number 2. It is available but will give a deprecation warning.  You should use the replacement.